# Городского округа Судака или городского округа Судак...?

Tags: склонение

Как пишется: «городского округа Судака» или «городского округа Судак»? Или вообще фиолетово?

Answer (score 1):

**Городского округа Судак.**
Родовое словосочетание *"городской округ"* не входит в список тех, после которых видовой топоним склоняется.
К тому же ориентируемся на [написание в официальных источниках](http://sudak.rk.gov.ru:8880/poisk-po-sajtu?searchword=%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B5&ordering=newest&searchphrase=all&limit=20).